# Format multiple Time columns based on one Date column in RStudio

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I could achieve the desired results with a series of `paste()` and `as.Date()` functions for each column individually, but is there a more efficient approach?

---

### Reprex

**Data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(Column = as.numeric(c(1:6)),
                  Headers = c("1989-01-01", "1990-01-01", "1991-01-01", "1992-01-01", "1993-01-01", "1994-01-01"),
                  Are = c("7:08:26 am", "7:08:34 am", "7:08:41 am", "7:08:45 am", "7:08:47 am", "7:08:48 am"),
                  Separated = c("Apples", "Bananas", "Cherries", "Dates", "Elderberries", "Figs"),
                  `And They` = c("7:36:48 am", "7:36:54 am", "7:36:59 am", "7:37:01 am", "7:37:01 am", "7:36:59 am"), 
                  Have = c("5:08:11 pm", "5:09:00 pm", "5:09:51 pm", "5:10:43 pm", "5:11:37 pm", "5:12:32 pm"),
                  Different = c("5:36:33 pm", "5:37:21 pm", "5:38:09 pm", "5:39:00 pm", "5:39:51 pm", "5:40:44 pm"),
                  Names = c("Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Violet"),
                  check.names = F)
```

**Data Frame**

```
> df
  Column    Headers        Are    Separated   And They       Have  Different  Names
1      1 1989-01-01 7:08:26 am       Apples 7:36:48 am 5:08:11 pm 5:36:33 pm    Red
2      2 1990-01-01 7:08:34 am      Bananas 7:36:54 am 5:09:00 pm 5:37:21 pm Orange
3      3 1991-01-01 7:08:41 am     Cherries 7:36:59 am 5:09:51 pm 5:38:09 pm Yellow
4      4 1992-01-01 7:08:45 am        Dates 7:37:01 am 5:10:43 pm 5:39:00 pm  Green
5      5 1993-01-01 7:08:47 am Elderberries 7:37:01 am 5:11:37 pm 5:39:51 pm   Blue
6      6 1994-01-01 7:08:48 am         Figs 7:36:59 am 5:12:32 pm 5:40:44 pm Violet
```

**Desired Output**

```
  Column    Headers                 Are    Separated            And They                Have           Different  Names
1      1 1989-01-01 1989-01-01 07:08:26       Apples 1989-01-01 07:36:48 1989-01-01 17:08:11 1989-01-01 17:36:33    Red
2      2 1990-01-01 1990-01-01 07:08:34      Bananas 1990-01-01 07:36:54 1990-01-01 17:09:00 1990-01-01 17:37:21 Orange
3      3 1991-01-01 1991-01-01 07:08:41     Cherries 1991-01-01 07:36:59 1991-01-01 17:09:51 1991-01-01 17:38:09 Yellow
4      4 1992-01-01 1992-01-01 07:08:45        Dates 1992-01-01 07:37:01 1992-01-01 17:10:43 1992-01-01 17:39:00  Green
5      5 1993-01-01 1993-01-01 07:08:47 Elderberries 1993-01-01 07:37:01 1993-01-01 17:11:37 1993-01-01 17:39:51   Blue
6      6 1994-01-01 1994-01-01 07:08:48         Figs 1994-01-01 07:36:59 1994-01-01 17:12:32 1994-01-01 17:40:44 Violet
```

Comment: please provide the result of a dput() function on your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may loop `across` the columns of interest `paste` the 'Column' with the individual columns and convert to datetime class with `ymd_hms` from `lubridate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
   mutate(across(Headers:Names, ~ ymd_hms(str_c(Column, ' ', .))))
```

-output

```
df1
 Column             Headers                Have           Different               Names
1 1989-01-01 1989-01-01 07:08:26 1989-01-01 07:36:48 1989-01-01 17:08:11 1989-01-01 17:36:33
2 1990-01-01 1990-01-01 07:08:34 1990-01-01 07:36:54 1990-01-01 17:09:00 1990-01-01 17:37:21
3 1991-01-01 1991-01-01 07:08:41 1991-01-01 07:36:59 1991-01-01 17:09:51 1991-01-01 17:38:09
4 1992-01-01 1992-01-01 07:08:45 1992-01-01 07:37:01 1992-01-01 17:10:43 1992-01-01 17:39:00
5 1993-01-01 1993-01-01 07:08:47 1993-01-01 07:37:01 1993-01-01 17:11:37 1993-01-01 17:39:51
6 1994-01-01 1994-01-01 07:08:48 1994-01-01 07:36:59 1994-01-01 17:12:32 1994-01-01 17:40:44
```

---

With the OP's new dput edit, the `Headers` is now the `Date` column

```
df %>%
     mutate(across(c(Are, `And They`, Have, Different),
         ~ ymd_hms(str_c(Headers, " ", .))))
```

-output

```
  Column    Headers                 Are    Separated            And They                Have           Different  Names
1      1 1989-01-01 1989-01-01 07:08:26       Apples 1989-01-01 07:36:48 1989-01-01 17:08:11 1989-01-01 17:36:33    Red
2      2 1990-01-01 1990-01-01 07:08:34      Bananas 1990-01-01 07:36:54 1990-01-01 17:09:00 1990-01-01 17:37:21 Orange
3      3 1991-01-01 1991-01-01 07:08:41     Cherries 1991-01-01 07:36:59 1991-01-01 17:09:51 1991-01-01 17:38:09 Yellow
4      4 1992-01-01 1992-01-01 07:08:45        Dates 1992-01-01 07:37:01 1992-01-01 17:10:43 1992-01-01 17:39:00  Green
5      5 1993-01-01 1993-01-01 07:08:47 Elderberries 1993-01-01 07:37:01 1993-01-01 17:11:37 1993-01-01 17:39:51   Blue
6      6 1994-01-01 1994-01-01 07:08:48         Figs 1994-01-01 07:36:59 1994-01-01 17:12:32 1994-01-01 17:40:44 Violet
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Column = c("1989-01-01", "1990-01-01", "1991-01-01", 
"1992-01-01", "1993-01-01", "1994-01-01"), Headers = c("7:08:26 am", 
"7:08:34 am", "7:08:41 am", "7:08:45 am", "7:08:47 am", "7:08:48 am"
), Have = c("7:36:48 am", "7:36:54 am", "7:36:59 am", "7:37:01 am", 
"7:37:01 am", "7:36:59 am"), Different = c("5:08:11 pm", "5:09:00 pm", 
"5:09:51 pm", "5:10:43 pm", "5:11:37 pm", "5:12:32 pm"), Names = c("5:36:33 pm", 
"5:37:21 pm", "5:38:09 pm", "5:39:00 pm", "5:39:51 pm", "5:40:44 pm"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6"))
```

Comment: What if my Time columns are separated by other columns that I don't want to merge? This is what I'm really trying to do and I will edit my example data to demonstrate.

Comment: @11hubertn then instead of `Header:Names` you can do `c(Headers, Have, Different, Names)`.  I assumed that the columns are in a range

Comment: Modified this for my real data, received an error:
```Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across(...)`.
x Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `Time End` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.``` I've also tried running without the ` ` symbols.

Comment: @11hubertn Based on your dput, the column names are now changed i.e. `df %>% mutate(across(c(Are, And, Have, Different), ~ ymd_hms(str_c(Headers, " ", .))))`

Comment: @11hubertn pleae check my update.  It workss fine with your data after chaning the column names

Comment: Modified my dput again to even better recreate my real-world data. Some of my column names have spaces in them!

Comment: @11hubertn that `dput` is throwing errors.  Can you check that dput again

Comment: @11hubertn the `And They` in your original data does it have space between or it is `.` in the column names because by default `data.frame` changes to `.` if there are spaces.  I used `check.names = FALSE`

Comment: I updated with the correction.  I am assuming there is a sspace in your column.  SO, I backquoted it.

Comment: @11hubertn I changed the code based on your multiple changes.  I don't know what exxaactly you are again changing?

Comment: Using the ` ` symbols to denote columns that use spaces as separators like `And They` doesn't seem to work for me, it returns the error message I commented above. Also, forgive me, I keep having to step away from my desktop :)

Comment: @11hubertn when you create `data.frame` wihtout `check.names = FALSE`, the `And They` is converted to `And.They` as i commented abvoe.

Comment: Yes, I had fixed that in my `dput` sneakily without you noticing. So the issue is that my column headers have spaces in the names, and I receive the error message above when running the offered solution. I tried using ` ` symbols and got the same error.

I think the issue was here: `str_c(Headers, ' ', .)` should be `str_c(Headers, " ", .)` For some reason it had single quotations in my RScript. Going to reattempt once I've reloaded my data. Also, this computer can't access chat, but I'll be able to soon. I vote to clean our discussion once everything's sorted

Comment: @11hubertn if you have very nasty names, use `library(janitor);df1 %>% clean_names() %>% the other operations` then you don't need to work with the space/no space issue.  Anyway, I showed you a case how to handle the space character.  It is also possible that your column names have leading/lagging spaces.  Not clear though?

Comment: No it's all been clear! Just found the fix - I forgot a letter in one of my column names. Been a long day! Thanks for sticking around.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr); library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(Headers:Names, ~ymd_hms(paste(Column, .x))))
```